# spark-submit: 403 error, client System:anonymous error

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, spark-submit

From time to time, when I submit spark job to Google Kubernetes cluster, I got 401 unauthorized, so I do this `gcloud container clusters get-credential my-cluster`, but it almost always followed by 403 error, saying client system:anonymous etc., but the weird the part is, I just need to do a simple `kubectl get namespace`, then it works again, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From time to time, when I submit spark job to Google Kubernetes cluster, I got 401 unauthorized

Your credentials expire.

> I do this `gcloud container clusters get-credential my-cluster`, but it almost always followed by 403 error, saying client system:anonymous etc.

Sounds like a timing issue where your new credentials and getting propagated in the cluster.